# Accessing my Home Desktop-Drive at Work or any other Location

Tags: networking, hard-drive, vpn

I would like to access my Home Desktop Drive at Work. I've searched around and found that setting up a VPN as follows https://pureinfotech.com/setup-vpn-server-windows-10/ will allow me to connect to my mapped home network drive. However my Public Ip Address changes as it isn't static and I need a way to effortlessly or automating connecting to my Home Desktop Drive instead of looking for my Public IP Address every morning.

My scenario is to access my DESKTOP PC Hard-Drive situated at Home from Work or Location. Which means I won't be on the same network. I need a method where it doesn't request me to check, input a new IP daily. Also I want it to be secure and less softwares as possible specially not TeamViewer as a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider setting up a dynamic DNS and an updater from a service such as [freedns.afraid.org](https://freedns.afraid.org/) you will then be able to use the same name every time rather than messing about with a dynamic IP.